# PowerShell command line import module

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a cmdlet under module M1. I need to run the cmdlet from commandline itself. Like say, `powershell -Command cmdlet1`.

But I need to import module M1 before running `cmdlet1`. Is there a way I can do this in one shot?

I don't want to interact with PowerShell, but I want to run `cmdlet1` just like I would run a normal Windows command.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 powershell -command "& { import-module M1; cmdlet1 }"
```

Or just:

```
 powershell -command "import-module M1; cmdlet1 "
```